# Art from a DJ needs to be Vectorized, anyone seen this before?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, logo

I have never posted on StackExchange before but enjoy reading the threads and have helped me start my own little hobby. A friend of mine works at a night club and is being told they need a vector logo for tshirts. I said no problem send me logo. I opened in Illustrator and see these random little lines everywhere. Before I go and create the art again for him in illustrator I wanted to see if anyone knew what this was or how this was caused? I asked him how he created the logo and said in photoshop but it is used on video boards. So I assume it is created in a different program all together and then he put it in photoshop and saved to send to the tshirt company.

Anyways long story short, do I need to recreate this art for him or is there a way to clean up these random lines quickly?

UPDATE: I started seperating the logo to patchs and notice these lines on just the curves. See second screenshot. I think I can just use the paths and create the logo again?[image]

Thanks- Thomas[image]

Comment: That's too messed up, time to start anew. The text part should not be hard to recreate.

Comment: Yeah, I already started and there's a lion at the top of this so that's the only part will take some time, the rest is text and objects. Thanks for the quick reply

Comment: Look for duplicate layers etc, but I think I maybe recall a similar issue posted. It is hard to find the post, but it was certainly a similar pathing error. One thing to try: export a PDF/"print to PDF"/place in indesign etc and see if it appears in the result. It may simply be an AI rendering error.

Comment: Yes I've seen it, I'm sure we have a question on this exact problem. Trying to locate it.

Comment: Toggle the CPU/GPU preview.

Answer (score -1):

have you try this, choose preset you like it most, minimize threshold and go to advanced tracing result?

on the menu tab choose -> Window -> Image Trace
[image]

Comment: This does not answer the question.  Additionally, Image Trace is a lazy man's way out.  If the logo has issues that mean it needs to be recreated, using Image Trace just means the underlying issues are still going to be present in the newly created design